# Podcast App not downloading episodes to IPhone

Tags: iphone, data-transfer, podcasts

for about the last week my podcast app on my iPhone 6+ has been preparing to download episodes but not downloading. Ian on iOS 8.3

This is serious I need to listen to Hansel minutes and history of revolutions!

I have tried shutdown app, clear download, logging out of iTunes etc.

Any suggestions

Comment: Interesting... Only thing I can think of is firewall blocking?? Try checking that...

Comment: Unless every wifi hotspot I connect to has suddenly started blocking the same port....

Comment: Could you perhaps scrape together some logs and put them on pastebin? It would help greatly. Find logs by plugging device into computer. On mac logs are in: `~/Library/Logs` and on Windows: `AppData/Roaming/Apple Computer/Logs`

Comment: Logs of what? Where would I get logs

Comment: Ok, I'll try that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem. I restarted the phone, cancelled the pending downloads and then started the downloads again and it seems to be working. Feel like I'm working with a Microsoft product :(

Comment: So simple, I kept on thinking I should try that.  The old solutions are still the best.